# how to call block of html code without rewrite it using jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-accordion

1. I have 2 common html div (common List , common form)
2. I have a bootstrap accordion. I want to show them in four different accordion menu, calling them from common place. not rewriting them in each accordion panel body.
3. how can I achieve it using jQuery
4. code Pan live: https://codepen.io/tobabin/pen/WNgGzON

```
<form class="bs-example" action="">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <label for='r11' style='width: 350px;'>
              <input type='radio' id='r11' name='occupation' value='Working' required /> myCommon List1
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"></a>
            </label>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          **<h3>Wanna Show here common list</h3>**
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <label for='r11' style='width: 350px;'>
              <input type='radio' id='r11' name='occupation' value='Working' required /> myCommon Form1
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"></a>
            </label>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            **<h3>Wanna Show here common Form</h3>**
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <label for='r11' style='width: 350px;'>
              <input type='radio' id='r11' name='occupation' value='Working' required /> myCommon Form2
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"></a>
            </label>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            **<h3>Wanna Show here common Form</h3>**
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class=panel-title>
            <label for='r12' style='width: 350px;'>
              <input type='radio' id='r12' name='occupation' value='Not-Working' required /> myCommonList2
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"></a>
            </label>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          **<h3>Wanna Show here common list</h3>**
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<!-----------------------------------**Common Element**--------------------------------->
<div class="**commonList**">
  <ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="**commonForm**">
    <form>
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
    </form>
</div>

<div>
</div>
```

I wish initially common html element will be disabled.

When jQuery called html element will be show(), hide() or called in specific position

Comment: Are you saying that you want to duplicate the list and form in _each_ accordion item body?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about the elements being initially disabled, but this will copy the "common" HTML elements into the panel bodies: https://codepen.io/76484/pen/ZEMpZQa